# Can not find type the return value of a class factory function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to make a function that returns a class, But I can not find what type definition it should be, I have created an example
for TestItem in interface IOtherFactory, I have tried

- `TestItem: ISomeClass<string>;`
- `TestItem: ReturnType<typeof moduleSomeFactory>;`
- `TestItem: { new <T extends ISomeClass<string>>(): T };`

Along with a few other variations., If I change `SomeThing<string>` to `SomeThing<any>` it works, but in the real code  that is not acceptable

Here is my code

```
export interface ISomeClass<T> {
  t: T;
}

export function moduleSomeFactory() {
  return class SomeClass<T> implements ISomeClass<T> {
    t: T;
    constructor(t: T) {
      this.t = t;
    }
  };
}

interface IOtherFactory {
  TestItem: ISomeClass<string>;
}

export function someOtherFactory(): IOtherFactory {
  const SomeThing = moduleSomeFactory();
  class TestItem extends SomeThing<string> {}
  return {
    TestItem,
  };
}
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile.  What is `SomeThing<>`?  It's really hard to understand your code because some of it doesn't make sense: `return { TestItem, }`?  That really isn't an `IOtherFactory` strictly speaking because you've defined a class TYPE that extends another class inside the method `someOtherFactory` but that TYPE is not a property of a object as you've returned.

Comment: It compiles if I change 
`interface IOtherFactory {
  TestItem: ISomeClass<string>;
}` to `interface IOtherFactory {
  TestItem: any;
}`  SomeThing is the output of moduleSomeFactory, I have a factory function, that I need to extend the output and limit its types

Comment: Sure it may compile, but it doesn't make sense.  You're mixing Types, classes and properties all over the place.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do. `someOtherFactory` should return a generic class ? Or should `T` be specified when invoking `someOtherFactory` or `someOtherFactory` is supposed to return a specific `Something` for some type parameter. There is syntax for all of these but I don't know what your intent is

Comment: I want to have IOtherFactory be the correct type, The implementation of what it is is sound, and functioning when the type is any ( I abstracted the code, so I didnt have to paste 100's of lines of code with irrelevant business logic to the question ), if it would help I could get you a pastebin of the actual code

Comment: @TimHolum if you just want to fix the type error, you need to use in the interface `TestItem:new (s: string) => ISomeClass<string>;` but I am not sure you want `someOtherFactory ` to generate just ` ISomeClass<string>` and not ` ISomeClass<T>` for some other `T`

Comment: Awesome that worked, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the type error you can specify a constructor signature that will return an `ISomeClass<string>`

```
export interface ISomeClass<T> {
    t: T;
}

export function moduleSomeFactory() {
    return class SomeClass<T> implements ISomeClass<T> {
        t: T;
        constructor(t: T) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    };
}

interface IOtherFactory {
    TestItem: new (s: string) => ISomeClass<string>;
}

export function someOtherFactory(): IOtherFactory {
    const SomeThing = moduleSomeFactory();
    class TestItem extends SomeThing<string> { }
    return {
        TestItem,
    };
}
```